# How to calculate a non-inflated count from a denormalized table

Tags: sql, postgresql, denormalization

Suppose I have a denormalized table that includes an ID and a value that I need to count. Something like this:

```
 Tree_ID | ...other columns... |  Count_If_True
------------------------------------------------
       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       2 | ...other values...  |           True
       2 | ...other values...  |           True
       3 | ...other values...  |           True
```

In this case, `select Tree_ID, count(Count_If_True) from Table group by Tree_ID` would show:

```
 Tree_ID |  count(Count_If_True)
---------------------------------
       1 |                     2
       2 |                     2
       3 |                     1
```

But If I denormalize my table further with a join from an `Apples` table (where every tree has multiple apples), it would look something like this:

```
Apple_ID | Tree_ID | ...other columns... |  Count_If_True
------------------------------------------------
       1 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       2 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       3 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       4 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       5 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       6 |       1 | ...other values...  |           True
       7 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
       8 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
       9 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      10 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      11 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      12 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      13 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      14 |       2 | ...other values...  |           True
      15 |       3 | ...other values...  |           True
      16 |       3 | ...other values...  |           True
      17 |       3 | ...other values...  |           True
      18 |       3 | ...other values...  |           True
      19 |       3 | ...other values...  |           True
```

This would inflate our `count` to:

```
 Tree_ID |  count(Count_If_True)
---------------------------------
       1 |                     6
       2 |                     8
       3 |                     5
```

Is there a simple way (without a CTE, for example) to write a single query to get back the original count result before `Apple_ID`s were introduced?

Comment: your first table have an unique ID? and the table that was joined, has a unique key? if yes you may use a windowed function patitioned by those Ids to get the count.. (or a sum with a case when)

Comment: Isn't this typical of a `M:M` relationship?  If you don't want to count each `apple`, then it should be in the query.  Also, it may help to have both table structures and the join you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a distinct row identifier in the first table -- perhaps that is among the other columns.  It can be one or more columns.  Then you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select tree_id,
       count(distinct <unique row column>) filter (where count_if_true)
from t
group by tree_id;
```

Comment: this works perfectly! the unique row column from the first table was indeed a composite of multiple columns

Comment: how would this work for a sum  instead of count? you can't sum a <unique row column>

Comment: @hov . . . I would recommend ask another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508081/how-to-calculate-a-non-inflated-sum-from-a-denormalized-table - asked here