# How to calculate a non-inflated SUM from a denormalized table

Tags: sql, postgresql, denormalization

this is kind of building off a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492463/how-to-calculate-a-non-inflated-count-from-a-denormalized-table/59493313#59493313). Suppose I have a denormalized table that looks something like this:

```
    Apple_ID | Tree_ID | Orchard_ID | Tree_Height | ...other columns...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           1 |       1 |          1 |          12 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           2 |       1 |          1 |          12 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           3 |       1 |          1 |          12 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           4 |       2 |          1 |          15 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           5 |       2 |          1 |          15 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           6 |       2 |          1 |          15 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           7 |       2 |          1 |          15 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           8 |       3 |          1 |          20 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
           9 |       3 |          1 |          20 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          10 |       4 |          2 |          30 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          11 |       5 |          2 |          10 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          12 |       5 |          2 |          10 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          13 |       5 |          2 |          10 |  ...other values...
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to calculate the sum of Tree_Heights in each orchard, so the result I want to get back is:

```
Orchard_ID | sum(Tree_Height)
-------------------------------
         1 |               47
-------------------------------
         2 |               40
```

However, due to the denormalization, the sum inflates to this:

```
Orchard_ID | sum(Tree_Height)
-------------------------------
         1 |              136
-------------------------------
         2 |               60
```

The solution from the question I mentioned before cannot be implemented here, since we cannot sum() by a unique row column. How can I write a simple query to get the intended result?

Comment: Based on your previous question, can't you just do these sums without joining to the apple table?

Comment: no, the point of both questions is that I'm trying to do these aggregations on a denormalized table

Comment: Are you trying to collect other data at the same time?

Comment: Does a `CTE` count as simple?

Comment: I'm writing an import query in Sisense which does not support CTEs

Comment: Not sure I understand the first question. In my real-world case, I will be doing multiple aggregate functions on the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to write this is with a `CTE`, but if your system doesn't support that you can use a derived table. We use `ROW_NUMBER()` over the `Apple_ID` for each tree to give us a unique row to sum:

```
SELECT "Orchard_ID", SUM("Tree_Height") AS Total_Height
FROM (
  SELECT "Orchard_ID", "Tree_Height", 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Orchard_ID", "Tree_ID" ORDER BY "Apple_ID") AS rn
  FROM data
) d
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY "Orchard_ID"
```

Output

```
Orchard_ID  total_height
1           47
2           40
```

If you could use `CTE`s this is how it would be written:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT "Orchard_ID", "Tree_Height", 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Orchard_ID", "Tree_ID" ORDER BY "Apple_ID") AS rn
  FROM data
)
SELECT "Orchard_ID", SUM("Tree_Height") AS Total_Height
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY "Orchard_ID"
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa1f5f/3)

Comment: this makes sense, however window functions are not supported by Sisense either

Comment: @hov it seems Sisense is a pretty small subset of PostgreSQL! :-) Can you point at the docs? I might be able to figure something out...

Comment: @hov what did you use as the "unique row column" in the previous answer?

Comment: for the last question, I used multiple ids from other joined tables as one  distinct row identifier. As for Sisense, their cube-level functions are here: https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/managing-data/transforming-data/function-reference/functions.htm#gsc.tab=0 It just occured to me that the aggregate function would have to happen there, after manually importing the necessary tables form a postgres DB

Comment: You might be able to do that here, removing `ROW_NUMBER()` and using that set of `id` values in place of the `WHERE rn = 1` clause or even something like `SUM(CASE WHEN unique_row_number condition is true THEN Tree_Height ELSE 0 END)` to avoid the subquery altogether

Comment: It looks like the Sisense equivalent of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Orchard_ID", "Tree_ID" ORDER BY "Apple_ID")` is `RANKASC(Orchard_ID, Tree_ID, Apple_ID)`